Bootloop due to permission denied error with custom product EROFS partition
I am trying to build a custom product partition from the stock ROM of my device and have gotten it to
boot the kernel with the correct mkfs.erofs and lpmake settings, as below:
mkfs.erofs product.img --file-contexts=plat_file_contexts -T1640995200 -U36ec0004-4050-5d1b-843d-e8aa8bc41a77 --force-uid=0 --force-gid=0 product

lpmake --metadata-size 65536 --super-name super --metadata-slots 2 --device super:11744051200 --group main:11744051200 --partition system:none:5915717632:main --image system=./super_contents/system.img --partition system_ext:none:404594688:main --image system_ext=./super_contents/system_ext.img --partition vendor:none:1382526976:main --image vendor=./super_contents/vendor.img --partition product:none:1609781248:main --image product=./product.img --partition odm:none:1593344:main --image odm=./super_contents/odm.img --sparse --output super.new.img

where the product directory in mkfs.erofs stores the contents of /product (extracted using fsck.erofs --extract), super_contents contains the stock partition images extracted from the stock super.img, and plat_file_contexts is the /system/etc/selinux/plat_file_contexts file from the phone.
When the device bootloops, it produces the following result in its rescueparty_log:
Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 648 (fsverity_init), pid 648 (fsverity_init)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Cmdline: /system/bin/fsverity_init --load-verified-keys
pid: 648, tid: 648, name: fsverity_init  >>> /system/bin/fsverity_init <<<
uid: 0
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'terminating with uncaught exception of type NSt3__14__fs10filesystem16filesystem_errorE: filesystem error: in posix_stat: failed to determine attributes for the specified path: Permission denied [/product/etc/security/fsverity]'

The issue is not caused by my lpmake settings, as I can build a fully functional custom super.new.img with the stock product.img. It has to do with the permission setup being specified incorrectly or insufficiently (somehow) in my mkfs.erofs configuration.
The files on the partition on the device are all owned by root, UID and GID 0:
a34x:/product # find . -exec stat -c "%u" {} + 2>/dev/null | sort -u 
0

a34x:/product # find . -exec stat -c "%g" {} + 2>/dev/null | sort -u
0

Building the partition with either --all-root or --force-guid=0 --force-uid=0 (as was done above) or both does not solve the issue.
Anything obvious about the partition system in Android that I am missing due to inexperience or something like that? All help is appreciated. Thanks.
The full rescueparty_log
--------- beginning of crash
Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 648 (fsverity_init), pid 648 (fsverity_init)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/a34xdtur/a34x:14/UP1A.231005.007/A346EXXS5BXA4:user/release-keys'
Revision: '6'
ABI: 'arm64'
Processor: '3'
Timestamp: 2024-04-26 20:48:22.208872000+0000
Process uptime: 0s
Cmdline: /system/bin/fsverity_init --load-verified-keys
pid: 648, tid: 648, name: fsverity_init  >>> /system/bin/fsverity_init <<<
uid: 0
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'terminating with uncaught exception of type NSt3__14__fs10filesystem16filesystem_errorE: filesystem error: in posix_stat: failed to determine attributes for the specified path: Permission denied [/product/etc/security/fsverity]'
    x0  0000000000000000  x1  0000000000000288  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000007ff96bf010
    x4  736f646277641f73  x5  736f646277641f73  x6  736f646277641f73  x7  7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
    x8  00000000000000f0  x9  00000071652ae110  x10 0000000000000001  x11 00000071652f7cc0
    x12 00000000000009be  x13 0000000009f2975f  x14 000af79e004778e0  x15 000000004cec4ec5
    x16 0000007165363cf8  x17 0000007165340660  x18 00000071673e2000  x19 0000000000000288
    x20 0000000000000288  x21 00000000ffffffff  x22 0000007ff96bf180  x23 0000007ff96bf140
    x24 ffffff80ffffffc8  x25 0000007165365f38  x26 0000000000000000  x27 0000000000000000
    x28 0000000000000000  x29 0000007ff96bf090
    lr  00000071652e82d8  sp  0000007ff96beff0  pc  00000071652e8304  pst 0000000000001000
12 total frames
backtrace:
      #00 pc 000000000005c304  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+164) (BuildId: 5f89913e15aa7088d03682fa8322b310)
      #01 pc 000000000004d144  /system/lib64/libc++.so (abort_message+276) (BuildId: 84acbd0e3703d0ed73c0df290de333b9)
      #02 pc 000000000004d360  /system/lib64/libc++.so (demangling_terminate_handler() (.__uniq.205383134706309982814331919004001075825)+272) (BuildId: 84acbd0e3703d0ed73c0df290de333b9)
      #03 pc 000000000004df98  /system/lib64/libc++.so (std::__terminate(void (*)())+8) (BuildId: 84acbd0e3703d0ed73c0df290de333b9)
      #04 pc 000000000004d5cc  /system/lib64/libc++.so (__cxxabiv1::failed_throw(__cxxabiv1::__cxa_exception*) (.__uniq.322141405278763512308061072235179479160)+28) (BuildId: 84acbd0e3703d0ed73c0df290de333b9)
      #05 pc 000000000004d524  /system/lib64/libc++.so (__cxa_throw+116) (BuildId: 84acbd0e3703d0ed73c0df290de333b9)
      #06 pc 00000000000072dc  /system/bin/fsverity_init (void std::__1::__fs::filesystem::__throw_filesystem_error<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, std::__1::__fs::filesystem::path const&, std::__1::error_code const&>(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, std::__1::__fs::filesystem::path const&, std::__1::error_code const&)+76) (BuildId: e96b090329454c55c645540289b89056)
      #07 pc 0000000000008a10  /system/bin/fsverity_init (std::__1::__fs::filesystem::detail::(anonymous namespace)::create_file_status(std::__1::error_code&, std::__1::__fs::filesystem::path const&, stat const&, std::__1::error_code*)+448) (BuildId: e96b090329454c55c645540289b89056)
      #08 pc 0000000000008818  /system/bin/fsverity_init (std::__1::__fs::filesystem::__status(std::__1::__fs::filesystem::path const&, std::__1::error_code*)+152) (BuildId: e96b090329454c55c645540289b89056)
      #09 pc 0000000000006890  /system/bin/fsverity_init (LoadKeyFromDirectory(int, char const*, char const*)+96) (BuildId: e96b090329454c55c645540289b89056)
      #10 pc 00000000000051c8  /system/bin/fsverity_init (main.cfi+312) (BuildId: e96b090329454c55c645540289b89056)
      #11 pc 0000000000054738  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__libc_init+104) (BuildId: 5f89913e15aa7088d03682fa8322b310)
mtk-brm-commit-id:67c4fd8595280e59ed4cb233548bcddb2e3e62c7
mtk-brm-change-id:I271e11d9d7aef919231192e44d5a4fbf78f789ff
mtk-brm-merge-id:none
!@*** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Required services extension package is missing, check config_servicesExtensionPackage.
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.getRequiredServicesExtensionPackageLPr(PackageManagerService.java:2848)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.<init>(PackageManagerService.java:2651)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.main(PackageManagerService.java:1817)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.startBootstrapServices(SystemServer.java:1630)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:1269)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:985)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:608)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
Error reporting crash
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.app.IActivityManager.handleApplicationCrash(android.os.IBinder, android.app.ApplicationErrorReport$ParcelableCrashInfo)' on a null object reference
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$KillApplicationHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:213)
    at com.samsung.isrb.IsrbHooks$ISRBExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(IsrbHooks.java:183)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1071)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1066)
    at java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:2306)
!@*** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Required services extension package is missing, check config_servicesExtensionPackage.
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.getRequiredServicesExtensionPackageLPr(PackageManagerService.java:2848)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.<init>(PackageManagerService.java:2651)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.main(PackageManagerService.java:1817)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.startBootstrapServices(SystemServer.java:1630)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:1269)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:985)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:608)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
Error reporting crash
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.app.IActivityManager.handleApplicationCrash(android.os.IBinder, android.app.ApplicationErrorReport$ParcelableCrashInfo)' on a null object reference
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$KillApplicationHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:213)
    at com.samsung.isrb.IsrbHooks$ISRBExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(IsrbHooks.java:183)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1071)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1066)
    at java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:2306)
!@*** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Required services extension package is missing, check config_servicesExtensionPackage.
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.getRequiredServicesExtensionPackageLPr(PackageManagerService.java:2848)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.<init>(PackageManagerService.java:2651)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.main(PackageManagerService.java:1817)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.startBootstrapServices(SystemServer.java:1630)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:1269)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:985)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:608)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
Error reporting crash
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.app.IActivityManager.handleApplicationCrash(android.os.IBinder, android.app.ApplicationErrorReport$ParcelableCrashInfo)' on a null object reference
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$KillApplicationHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:213)
    at com.samsung.isrb.IsrbHooks$ISRBExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(IsrbHooks.java:183)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1071)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1066)
    at java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:2306)
!@*** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Required services extension package is missing, check config_servicesExtensionPackage.
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.getRequiredServicesExtensionPackageLPr(PackageManagerService.java:2848)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.<init>(PackageManagerService.java:2651)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.main(PackageManagerService.java:1817)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.startBootstrapServices(SystemServer.java:1630)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:1269)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:985)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:608)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
Error reporting crash
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.app.IActivityManager.handleApplicationCrash(android.os.IBinder, android.app.ApplicationErrorReport$ParcelableCrashInfo)' on a null object reference
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$KillApplicationHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:213)
    at com.samsung.isrb.IsrbHooks$ISRBExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(IsrbHooks.java:183)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1071)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1066)
    at java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:2306)

